# How do I remove the BIOS password on a Thinkpad T61

Tags: bios, lenovo-laptop

I want to remove the BIOS Password on a Thinkpad T61 Laptop.

I removed the CMOS Battery for few days and reinstalled it but I still have the same password issue.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: See https://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/42x3550_03.pdf page 26.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the CMOS jumper that is present near the battery itself for about 10 seconds (or more).
If that doesn't work, try restoring the default settings. You'll get an option there in the bios settings. But again, you must check if there are any back-draws of doing such a thing.